# Will IOS 5 built in API for JSON parsing work on lower version phones?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json, parsing

IOS 5 has some new built-in APIs to make it really easy to read and write JSON. If i'm building an app using these APIs, will it work on the devices with lower versions of IOS??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, since it is not available. iOS 5 only classes and methods will only work iOS 5 and higher.

In the documentation of [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it states that it is Availability as "Available in iOS 5.0 and later."

You could always check if a class is available like:

```
if ([NSJSONSerialization class]) {
   // Yes the class is available.
}
```

Comment: So all the APIs in the later versions will be like this? They don't have back ward compatibility?

Comment: How should previous iOS version know about the `NSJSONSerialization` classes?